# Сделать label к полям в форме с помощью цикла

Tags: php, yii

Есть код:

```
foreach ($doors as $door) {
 echo CHtml::activeLabel($door,'1');
 echo CHtml::activeTextField($door,'sum');
}
```

Он рисует форму (на картинке), как делать чтобы к каждому полю в качестве подписи добавлялось 1, 2 и 3, а не 1 ко всем.
[image: вот фото]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это просто вам всего лишь нужно добавить счётчик, например:

```
foreach ($doors as $key => $door) {
     echo CHtml::activeLabel($door, $key);
     echo CHtml::activeTextField($door, 'sum');
}
```

или если у вас есть id в $door

```
foreach ($doors as $door) {
     echo CHtml::activeLabel($door, 'id');
     echo CHtml::activeTextField($door, 'sum');
}
```

Comment: добрый день, спасибо) Но я сглупила с формулировкой вопроса, там должны быть не цифры, а названия т.е слова)

Comment: название дверей? а где эти названия у вас хранятся? распечатайте в цикле $door и добавьте значение в котором хранится название в мой пример вместо 'id'

Comment: ну да, можно сказать дверей)

Comment: лучше скажите проще, что у вас лежит в переменной $doors

Comment: Проблема в том что 'sum', делает сразу три поля, а названия у них должны быть разные

Comment: sum(CASE WHEN door = 2 and type = 1 THEN sum ELSE 0 END)::int as door_type_2, так данные отображаются в таблицу, а я сейчас пытаюсь делать форму для редактирования

Comment: сами названия, вот) return [
   'id' => 'ID',
   'sum' => 'Sum',
   'door' => 'door',
   'type' => 'Type',

Comment: если вам нужно в label записать type или door так и напишите CHtml::activeLabel($door, 'type');